# How to achieve nested restangular call in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, restangular

How to achieve nested restangular call in angularjs.
From the first restangular call, I'm retrieving some id. Then I want to make another call to retrieve the details of that id within first call.

Answer (score 0):

Since restangular returns a promise

You can do as follows:

```js
FirstRestangularCall()
  .then(function(r) {
    return SecondMethod(r);
  }, handleErr)
  .then(function(r) {
    return ThirdMethod(r);
  }, handleErr);
```

Hope it helps..